# How can i visualise my datasets knowing that i have 9 attributs?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, visualization

I Am treating  Breast cancer dataset the original one (classification)
in many websites i found that they did he visualisation like that :

X-axis for attribute1
Y-axis for attribut2

they have just two attributes like input and the class attribute = (0,1)
and also they draw the hypothesis plot on that visualisation
in my case I have 9 attributes

**how can i do it? i choose any two attributs or what ?**

its more like a presentation of the data .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible for the human mind to process more than 3 dimensions. So even if you did somehow visualize 9 dimensions, you wouldn't be able to infer anything from it. 
I d rather suggest you to take 2 or 3 features at a time and visualize multiple plots. Having said that, there are some plots which let you accommodate more than 3 features also.
Try this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-visualization-for-machine-learning-and-data-science-a45178970be7).

This [kaggle kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/kanncaa1/feature-selection-and-data-visualization) uses the same Breast Cancer dataset and has some interesting insights on visualization.